# Как в dnlib получить значение поля?

Tags: c#, строки, dnlib

У меня есть программа, в ней есть класс Program, в нём поле TestString, это поле равно "qwerty":
Вот программа под dnSpy:

```
public static class Program
{
    public static string TestString = "qwerty":
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(TestString);
    }
}
```

Вот то, что я смог написать по примерам и докам dnlib:

```
var mod = ModuleDefMD.Load(path, ModuleDef.CreateModuleContext());
var programClass = mod.Find("TestProgram.Program", false);

foreach(var field in programClass.Fields)
    if(field.Name == "TestString")
        Console.WriteLine( => вот тут должен быть Value <= );
```

Как получить значение этой строки?

Comment: Никогда не работал с данной библиотекой, но я бы написал `field`, поставил точку и посмотрел бы на предложения автокомплита. Наверняка там найдётся какое-то говорящее имя типа (surprise!) `field.Value`. Вот вы написали `foreach(var field` и `if(field.Name` - ну подумайте на шаг дальше, что там может быть? Конечно бывают такие мудрёные случаи, когда нужно сначала скастить field к чему-то типа `BlahBlahBlahTextField` и тут без документации не обойтись -- но самый-то очевидный случай вы попробовали?

Comment: К счастью, я не тупой. Я раз 20 пересмотрел все, что может быть после точки, и даже зашёл дальше по уровням, но ничего, хоть отдалённо напоминающего Value, не было

Comment: Вы не обижайтесь, просто в тексте вопроса об этом ни слова. Телепатов, кто могут узнать в ненаписанном тексте полезную информацию, увы, нету.

Comment: Я уже пробовал AsmResolver.DotNet:
```var needsString = ModuleDefinition.FromFile(path).GetAllTypes().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Program").Fields.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "TestString");```
Однако, тут тоже нет поля Value